# How to secretly save a usage counter?

Tags: .net, windows, registry

I'm working on a .NET application for Windows 7/8/2003/2008/XP in which I have to store a usage counter somewhere. I don't want the user to find and change it (or at least I want it to be very hard to find and change it).
This is a free edition I provide for technical users in big enterprise shops. I want to let them use it 10 times a day or 30 times at all.

I thought to save it encrypted into Windows Registry, however I've just found that I can't save to anywhere else local user if the application is installed by non-local admin user.

I do want to let non-local admin users to install it, so what should I do? 
I consider to save it to files in `%appdata%` - would you do the same?

Looking forward to hearing any advice... Thank you

Comment: Do any of the answers here help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442443/is-there-some-sort-of-secure-local-storage-on-windows

Comment: Impossible, at least for technical users :) And, if I ever need to try out many similar apps, I usually skip ones with stupid counter tricks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that in your case it doesn't matter WHERE you save it but HOW you save it.
**[Encrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2150863/1379664)** the data of your counter and add the *encrypted* data to the registry (or save it as a file in your application's directory).
Prevent your application from running if the data is ever modified or deleted.