# Retrieve credentials from windows credential manager

Tags: ruby

I was disappointed to know that my colleague said there is no ruby library which will help us to access windows credentials and store it somewhere (but python does) so that my ruby script can use it to authenticate. I looked around a little bit and found nothing, so is this true or do we have some way to do it.

My information was python can achieve this using win32cred.

**[EDIT]:** Would like to retrieve credentials from the Windows Credential manager
and if it cannot find them then I would want to launch the Credential Password dialog
which is the built in credential manager dialog and captures the username
and password and saves it to the credential manager.

Comment: Are you using Active Directory?

Comment: you could write an FFI wrapper to CryptDataProtect http://stackoverflow.com/a/442509/32453 if that's what you mean by "access windows credentials and store it somewhere"

Comment: @rogerdpack: Yes I would want to achieve the same is there some way to do it in ruby?

Comment: @JustinWood Not using Active directory

Answer (score 1):

use FFI to call the CryptProtectData/CryptUnProtectData methods https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Windows-Examples

Comment: Ok, use FFI to wrap CredWrite/CredRead apparently (NB that this is less portable and doesn't support XP... http://stackoverflow.com/q/9221245/32453)